# Standard deviation of two variables in a portfolio

Tags: statistics, finance

An investor forms a portfolio by putting 25% of his money into Google stock and 75% into Amazon stock. He expects a return on investment (ROI) of 8% from Google, and 15% from Amazon. The standard deviation of ROI is 12% for Google and 22% for Amazon. Compute the standard deviation of the portfolio's total ROI assuming that Google and Amazon returns are independent.

The professor has posted the answer to this problem:

Let $G$ be the money put into Google, and $A$ be the money put into Amazon. Then
Var$(0.25G+0.75A) = 0.25^2 * 0.12^2 + 0.75^2*0.22^2 = 0.028$.

But I don't quite understand the answer. If $G$ means the money invested into Google, then what does $0.25G$ mean? I get the intuition that 25% of the variance will be based on the variance of $G$, but the formula just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Var[aX + bY] = a^2*Var[X] + b^2*Var[Y]   (if X and Y are independent variables and a and b are constants)

The SD's are getting squared and the amounts of money invested are too.

Comment: The 0.25G is representing how much Google stock they can buy with 25% of their money, and the 0.75A is representing the amount of Amazon stock they can buy with the remaining 75%. You are calculating the amount of variability of this total amount of stock.

I think his answer should have a (0.25G)^2 term and a (0.75A)^2 term to be consistent with the notation, it looks like they just drop the G and the A.

Comment: @Michael I get the formula part and have no problem with it. What bothers me is that if you use 25% of your money, shouldn't your formula be $0.25X$ where $X$ is your total money? Why is it $0.25G$?

Comment: It's the amount of Google stock you can buy if you spend 25 cents out of every dollar you have on Google stock. 

I think the explanation of "Let G be the money put into Google, and A be the money put into Amazon"  can't be totally right, because if they were the $ amounts, then 4G=A and you wouldn't need the additional 25% and 75% in there because you already took that into account.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that's what confuses me. So what do $G$ and $A$ actually mean in $0.25G+0.75A$? Your explanation that "$0.25G$ is the amount of Google stock you can buy if you spend 25 cents out of every dollar you have on Google stock" still makes me feel that this should be $0.25X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invest $x_1$ in an asset with return $r_1$ and $x_2= 1-x_1$ in another asset with return $r_2$, the overall return on your portfolio is
$$x_1r_1+x_2r_2$$

Likewise, $G$ is the r.v. corresponding to the ROI on Google, and $A$ is for the ROI on Amazon. These two variables do not represent the money invested, that is given by the fraction of your investment put in either stock (25% and 75% in your example).

Comment: Ah, yes... the variables should be the returns instead. Thanks!